# ¿Cómo puedo dibujar en PHP (u otro lenguaje orientado a la web) un polígono como el de la imagen?

Tags: aplicación-web, programación-funcional

La idea es que tras realizar un test (cada pregunta pondera a ámbito-vértice del polígono), extraer los datos y dibujar el polígono con el resultado. He consultado el siguiente [recurso](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledpolygon.php) y puede ser de ayuda, pero la imagen creo que es de una complejidad mayor.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda, aquí os dejo la imagen de ejemplo:

[image: pentagonoPrueba]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una libreria de Javascript muy sencilla de usar llamada Chart.JS.
Aquí dejo un demo de la gráfica que quieres hacer:
http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/area/radar.html

Aquí el example code para crear el Chart Radar:
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/radar.html

y aquí la página de Chart.JS:
http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/

Espero te sea de utilidad, un abrazo!

Comment: Muchas gracias Othon, una excelente manera de empezar!